# media files stores files in MEDIA_ROOT, but serves them from app folder

Tags: django

I'm having trouble bending the media_root to my will.

When I try to serve an image, a suffix is appended to the file path, more precisely, it tries to point to an app (yoga) even though I want it to point to BASE_DIR / media.

For example it will give me this:

> http://localhost:8000/yoga/media/images/satori.jpg

But the media folder is (auto-generated) one folder up from that in the dir hierarchy.

I've been wracking my brain, because I just can't see where that "yoga/" line is appended to the path, and I don't understand why or how it got there, lest of course we consider, that the model that it stems from lives inside the yoga app directory.

Here's what I think might be relevant. Please let me know if you want to see more of the goods.

Tree:

```
  .
  ├── boofers.txt 
  ├── db.sqlite3 
  ├── dos_env
  ├── manage.py
  ├── media
  ├── static
  ├── yoga
  └── yoga_dos
```

In settings.py:

> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

in the model @ yoga/models.py:

> ex_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images', blank=True,
> default='yogapose.jpg')

in the main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('yoga/', include('yoga.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

...and in yoga/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.mk_json, name='yoga')
```

]

Comment: Can you also share your urls.py files?

Comment: Certainly! I've added to the OP :)

Comment: Are you providing a custom `upload_to` function on your `ImageField`/ `FileField` ?

Comment: I have an upload_to='media/images' param in there, but I reckon that's not what you're asking. I haven't done much to the project, and what I have done is exclusively vanilla (ie. following the standard practice from djangoproject.com). - Or at least as far as I know...

Comment: Smells like a relative url. Add leading slash when referencing images.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this:

```
http://localhost:8000/yoga/media/images/satori.jpg
```

Because, you are added this way in models.py:

```
upload_to='media/images',
```

To solve this, just add following way:

```
upload_to='images/'
```

Output look like this after adding above code:

```
http://localhost:8000/media/images/satori.jpg
```

Note: Don't create media folder inside your project or app. It will create media folder automatically inside your project.

Comment: Alas, that leaves me with:
`GET /yoga/images/satori.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404` in the server's output (ie. media/ is omitted from the string while the "yoga/"-bit stays).

Comment: instead of imagefield use filefield

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, I'm afraid. Either way the string will remain the same. Today I'll research some of my old projects and find out exactly what's going on here. Thanks for trying ;)